# lucene 4.2 query docs that doesn't contain specified field

Tags: java, lucene

```
if (post.getRefUserId() != null) {
    Field refUserId = new LongField("ref_user_id", post.getRefUserId(),
            Store.YES);
    fields.add(refUserId);
}
```

I index the field ref_user_id if it exists.

> I want to query docs with no ref_user_id field indexed, how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems give the field with a default value(0 or something else) is the only solution I can come up with.

The better solution

> `*:*` AND `-ref_user_id:[* TO *]`